# use sed/awk/cat to get the data between to //

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep, cat

I have a text file , which is always a different content on it , my test file is :

```
/home/bob/www/file
```

but it always change to a new line like

```
/home/joe/www/file3
```

How can I extract just the field with the user , nothing else , I dont know when bob is on the file I dont know when joe is on the file , it is always a different username , how can I export the user into a new file using cat/awk/sed or grep , anything similiar to that , I have search a lot but I found no results

From my file test , I want to extract just bob into a new file, is that posible? without knowing the word to extract, something to tell to extract the word between the /slash /slash and /slash

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` with `PCRE`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=/home/)[^/]+' testfile
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F/ '{print $3}' testfile
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's,/[^/]\+/\([^/]\+\)/.*,\1,' testfile
```

Using `bash`:

```
while IFS='/' read -ra name; do 
  echo "${name[2]}"; 
done < testfile
```

Comment: @Svan You're welcome. If the answer helped, please remember to click on the check mark to mark the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the username is always the 2nd component of the path, and that the path is always absolute (starts with "/")

```
username=$(cut -d/ -f3 < filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

the regular expression

```
/home/([a-z]*)/www/file
```

will match the line in question and capture the name. I'm not up on awk, so I can't tell you how to apply this, but maybe this will help you find your way.

Comment: Can usernames contain digits?

Comment: +1 Good point - you might have to modify that [a-z] to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `awk -F"/" '{printf( "%s\n", $3) }' test > newfile`.  Here, awk is reading the input file of "test", parsing by "/" and then printing the 3rd field ( after the 2nd "/" ) into a new file called "newfile".